# How can I collapse border of only one row in table HTML

Tags: html, css, border

I've been trying to collapse borders in my last two rows of Table, but I can't get the result I want, I already tried using `border:hidden, border: 0, border-collapse: collapse`. But nothing seems to work, I'm very new at this, If you guys have any solution for me, I'd be really glad.

Here is my HTML table code:

```css
.stock-table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  min-width: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-collapse: separated;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .25em .25em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.stock-table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-right: hidden;
}

.stock-table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.stock-table tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.directTR:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.stock-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #009879;
}

.stock-table td {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.stock-table thead tr {
  background-color: #009879;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<table class = "stock-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td> DRUG </td>
      <td> MEASURE </td>
      <td> AMOUNT </td>
      <td> COST </td>
      <td> TOTAL </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <c:forEach items = "${detailsList}" var = "detail">
      <tr class = "directTR">
        <td> ${detail.medicine_name} </td>
        <td> ${detail.medicine_measure} </td>
        <td> ${detail.amount} </td>
        <td> <span>$</span>${detail.price}</td>
        <td> <span>$</span>${detail.total}</td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <tr class = "finalTR">
      <td>subTotal:</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span>$</span>${subtotal}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "finalTR">
      <td>Total (+IVA):</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span>$</span>${total}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The borders I want to remove are:

[image: My Table]